# In numpy array slicing, i put array[:0], and output was "array([], dtype=int64)"

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

can anyone explain output, why it is like this

[This is screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU64j.png)

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = [0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
arr2 = np.array(arr1)
arr2[:0]

output:
array([], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Please enter the content of the image as text.

Comment: Please provide more detail about what you do and do not understand. Do you know how slicing works in general? Do you know what ``[:0]`` would mean when applied to a list?

Comment: arr2[:0] means "give me everything in arr2 up to the 0th element", which of course is nothing

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for slicing is `arr[start:end]`. It returns the elements from start till end, excluding the end.
Thus, when you give `arr[:0]`, it starts from 0, and stops at 0, but 0 is excluded, i.e. arr[0] is excluded. Hence you get an empty array

Answer (score 0):

`array[:i]` means 'elements of array up to and including i-1'. So, e.g. `array[:2]` will contain elements 0 and 1. In your case, you exlcude all elements.

Comment: "up to and including i-1" in this case would mean "up to and including -1", since ``i`` is 0. -1 is the last element of the list, and including all elements up to and including it would be the entire list.

Comment: You're right, I should have clarified that it deosn't wrap around in this specific case.